# Making a horizontal line take up the rest of the space to the right of text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a section header that has:

**HEADER NAME** -------------------------------------------------

Where the multiple ----'s are the horizontal rule.  Sadly, `hr`'s like to take up their own line.

Any ideas?  I would really prefer to do this all in CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off doing this using a table with two coulmns.

So your HTML would be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>MOO</h1></td>
        <td class="long"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and your CSS something like this:

```
.long {
    width:100%;
}
```

Here is the an example of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/xzcX2/

Answer (score 4):

A slightly complex method, which relies on some tortuous mark-up:

```
<h1 title="Header text">Header text<span></span></h1>
```

And CSS:

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    text-indent: 0;
}
h1:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
h1 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 49%;
    bottom: 49%;
    min-width: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L8fab/).

This is posted because it works, albeit presumably not in IE (I have no capacity to test that assumption at the moment, but use of the `:after` pseudo-element suggests that it's unlikely. It is, though, an option for the newer, up-to-date and standards-compliant browsers. So perhaps IE9+?

Answer (score 2):

can do this with a container element and set the header/hr to `position:absolute`

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/9B9Ug/)

```
<div id="headerContainer">
    <hr />
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#headerContainer {position:relative;font-size:20px;height:30px;}
hr {position:absolute;width:100%;}
h1 {position:absolute;background-color:#fff;padding:0 20px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="float: left;">My title</span><hr />
```

Should give you a heads start!

Comment: Unlike other solutions, this one does not require you to set a fixed background color on the text to hide the line going behind the text. 

You can position the `hr` by setting it to `position: relative` and using `top: 1em`, for example. [You can style the `hr`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_hr.asp) by using border styling like `border: 1px solid #999`.

Answer (score 0):

One method: Use `float: left`:

```
<span style="float: left;">Heading</span><hr style="float: left; width: 95%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is inline-block

```
<span>TEXT<hr style="display:inline-block;width:95%;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least two options:
1. use image witch repeated background as line, and solid color for text-background (provided background is solid color)
2. (imho better):

```
div { border-top:1px solid black; height:20px; line-height:20px;}
div > span { position:relative; top:-12px; background:white; display:inline-block;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCAQK/).